# Group Theory of order in $S_{10}$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

What is the order of $(3\ 7)(4\ 5)$ in $S_{10}$?

Answer: Order $2$

Is my answer correct?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Permutations with distinct supports commute.

Comment: What does that mean? Give me examples please

Comment: the support are the elements which are moved by the permutation. so for example if you have (13) and (24), we know that (13)(24)=(24)(13)

Comment: so in this case (3 7)(4 5)=(4 5)(3 7) therefore answer 2 is right?

Comment: If (4 5) does have order 2 surely, does it have order 2 ?

Comment: Yes it does (45) have order 2

Comment: So yes you do have order 2